# How to read excel file into python from a particular website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, request

I am trying to read several excel files available on this website https://www.motilaloswalmf.com/download/month-end-portfolio, using python's request library. However I am not able to figure out the exact url for downloading excels through network tab.

Can someone please help with it ? Thank you !

Comment: Provide the code you have you tried so far if anything. But the Links you are searching for are in the page source. Why are you trying to get them from Network

Comment: @iamtrappedman I had checked the source code, but don't see the url for the excel files. Could you please point them out  ?

Comment: open `view-source:https://www.motilaloswalmf.com/download/month-end-portfolio`. then search for `https://www.motilaloswalmf.com/CMS/assets/uploads/Documents/d7009-copy-of-in_mf_motilal_factsheet_31-08-2022_final.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

The given site needs JS rendering to extract the excel file links. You need selenium or playwright to achieve your goal.